Problem 32 (p.416) from chapter Multiple integrals of Tom Apostol's Calculus Vol II

Let $S_n(a)$ denote the following set in n-space, where $a > 0$ and $n
 \geq 2$: $$S_n(a) = \{ (x_1, \dots, x_n) \mid |x_i| + |x_n| \leq a
 \text{ for each } i = 1, \dots, n-1 \}.$$
(a) Make a sketch of $S_n(1)$ when $n = 2$ and when $n = 3$.
(b) Let $V_n(a) = {\int \dots \int}_{S_n(a)} dx_1 \dots dx_n$, and
show that $V_n(a) = a^n V_n(1)$.
(c) Express the integral for $V_n(1)$ as an iteration of a
one-dimensional integral and an $(n-1)$-fold integral, and deduce that
$V_n(a) = \dfrac{2^n a^n}{n}$.

For part b) we have the following formular: $$V_n(a)=\int_{S_n(a)} 1 dx$$with $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$
Let set $x=at$ with $t=(t_1,...,t_n)$. Under this transformation, each $x_i$ gets scaled by $a$, and the set $S_n(a)$ is transformed into $S_n(1)$.The Jacobian determinant of this transformation is $a^n$ so the volume of the transformed region scales by $a^n$.This gives:
$$V_n(a)=a^nV_n(1)$$
I'm stuck at part c). Could someone help me? Thanks in advance!

I misread the problem in my other answer, calculating the volume of the regular cross-polytope using induction on dimension. This exercise is more straightforward.
It relies on the knowing the volume of the hypercube in dimension $m$ of side length $2b$, i.e., the set of points $(x_1, \dots, x_m)$ satisfying $-b \leq x_i \leq b$, or equivalently $|x_i| \leq b$, for each $i = 1, \dots, m$. Using the standard notation, we can call this region $[-b, b]^m$. It's pretty clear that we can restrict to the positive orthant (all coordinates positive) then double the (hyper-)volume once for each dimension, yielding $2^m b^m$.
Now for the setup of the integral to calculate the volume $V_n(1)$ of the region $S_n(1)$. For each $i = 1, \dots, n-1$, the inequality $|x_i| + |x_m| \leq 1$ is equivalent to $|x_i| \leq 1 - |x_n|$. For each value of $b = 1 - |x_n|$, this defines the hypercube $[-b, b]^{n-1}$ of volume $2^{n-1}b^{n-1} = 2^{n-1}(1 - |x_n|)^{n-1}$.
Which values of $x_n$ are possible? Any of the inequalities $|x_i| + |x_m| \leq 1$ can be rearranged to show that
$$
0 \leq |x_m| \leq 1 - |x_i| \leq 1.
$$
Hence, our integral is
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_n(1) &= \int_{[-1, 1]} \int_{[-1 + |x_n|,\, 1 - |x_n|]^{n-1}} 
\mathrm{d}V_{n-1} \, \mathrm{d}x_n \\
&= \int_{-1}^{1} 2^{n-1} \bigl( 1 - |x_n| \bigr)^{n-1} \, \mathrm{d}x_n \\
&= 2^{n-1} \cdot 2 \int_0^1 ( 1 - x_n )^{n-1} \, \mathrm{d}x_n, 
\end{aligned}
$$
where the last step relies on the integrand being an even function. Now the substitution $u = 1 - x_n$ finishes off the calculation:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_n(1) &= 2^n \int_1^0 u^{n-1} \, (-\mathrm{d}u) \\
&= 2^n \int_0^1 u^{n-1} \, \mathrm{d}u \\[2pt] 
&= \frac{2^n}{n}.
\end{aligned}
$$

First of all, there's a typo in your formulas. The volume is smaller (note the factorial in the denominator):
$$
V_n(a) = \frac{2^n a^n}{n!}. 
$$
This convex region goes by several names cross-polytope, orthoplex, hyperoctahedron: $S_n(a)$ is the ball of radius $a$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ under the taxicab norm. Since $S_n(1)$ is defined by the inequality
$$
|x_1| + |x_2| + \cdots + |x_n| \leq 1, 
$$
a bit of rearranging yields
$$
0 \leq |x_1|  \leq 1 - \bigl( |x_2| + \cdots + |x_n| \bigr) \leq 1.
$$
So, it suffices to integrate $x_1$ over the interval $[-1, 1]$. For each such $x_1$, the same inequality rearranged again to
$$
|x_2| + \cdots + |x_n| \leq 1 - |x_1|
$$
shows that the coordinates $(x_2, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ form the solid $S_{n-1}\bigl( 1 - |x_1| \bigr)$ in each cross-sectional "slice". This is a full size $(n-1)$-dimensional $S_{n-1}(1)$ at the center $(x_1 = 0)$, and shrinks linearly to a degenerate point $S_{n-1}(0)$ at either end $(|x_1| = 1)$.
Manipulate the slider in this interactive graphic to visualize the $2$-dimensional cross-sections (diamonds) in the $3$-dimensional ball (octahedron).

By induction, we may assume the formula for these cross-sectional volumes. Hence,
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_n(1) &= \int_{S_n(1)} \mathrm{d}V_n \\
&= \int_{[-1, 1]} \int_{S_{n-1}(1 - |x_1|)} \mathrm{d}V_{n-1} \, \mathrm{d}x_1 \\
&= \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{2^{n-1} \bigl( 1 - |x_1| \bigr)^{n-1}}{n-1} \, \mathrm{d}x_1 \\
&= \frac{2^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} \cdot 2 \int_{0}^{1}  \bigl( 1 - x_1 \bigr)^{n-1} \, \mathrm{d}x_1 \\
&= \frac{2^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} \cdot \frac{2}{n} \\
&= \frac{2^{n}}{n!}
\end{aligned}
$$

You misunderstood. $S_n(1)$ is not defined by $$|x_1|+...+|x_n|\leq 1$$

this problem from Tom Apostol'calculus book seems challenging

anyone .......?

I wrote another answer to your question, @AlexNguyen
